# Creating a sequence of structs during runtime in c

Tags: c, struct, runtime, typedef

I want to create the game Snake in c. I need help or a push in the rigth direction to create a tale for the snake.

Currently my snake is built up on these three structs:

```
// Defines what a point is in the display
typedef struct {
  char x,y;
} POINT, *PPOINT;

// Defines the geometry of something
typedef struct tGeometry {
    int numpoints;
    int sizex; // Size in x-axis
    int sizey; // Size in y-axis
    POINT px [ MAX_POINTS ]; 
} GEOMETRY, *PGEOMETRY;

// Defines the object of something with a certain geometry
typedef struct tObj {
    PGEOMETRY geo;
    int dirx,diry;
    int posx,posy;
} OBJECT, *POBJECT;
```

The snake and its geometry is defined in the following way:

```
GEOMETRY snake_part_geometry =
    {
        16,
        4,4,
        {
            {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {0,3},
            {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3},
            {2,0}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3},
            {3,0}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,3},
            }
        };

static OBJECT snake_o = {
    &snake_part_geometry, /* The geometry for one part of the snakes body */
    0,0, /* starting direction */
    WIDTH/2,HEIGTH/2, /* starting position */
};
```

My problem comes when I want to make the tail of the snake. I need to create something new every time that the snake its a fruit, which follows the head of the snake and gets the posititon and direction of the body part in front of it.

I've thougth of something like this:

```
typedef struct _Tale{
    int length;
    POBJECT tale;
    } TALE, *PTALE; 

void create_new_tale (void) {
PTALE tale = malloc(sizeof(TALE));
tale->length++;
tale->tale = malloc(tale->length*sizeof(OBJECT));

tale->tale[0].posx = snake->posx;
tale->tale[0].posy = snake->posy;
for(int i = 1 ; i < tale->length ; i++){
    tale->tale[i].posx = tale->tale[i-1].posx;
    tale->tale[i].posy = tale->tale[i-1].posy;
    }   
for(int i = 1 ; i < tale->length ; i++){
    free(tale->tale[i].posx);
    free(tale->tale[i].posy);
    }
free(tale->tale);
free(tale);
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!
Albin

Comment: Just about any beginners book or tutorial should have chapters about pointers, and how to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, thanks for the replay! Is there something certain context that I should to the post for you to be able to understand more about the program.
I also updated the post with one of my attempts with malloc.